# Wifi not recognize in elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera

Tags: wifi, release-hera

I can't get wifi to work...I can't even see the wifi icon, I can only log in with cable. I installed windows wireless drivers and wifi radar...I also reinstalled the elementaryke OS... also my keyboard is not responsive when trying to write au comment in YouTube
I have a HP laptop 15-bw0xx

Answer (score 0):

this is because you probably need proprietary drivers for your wifi card.
But, before proceeding, is your wifi card detected from the system? Could you please report the result of lshw?
It would be very helpful to solve your issue, because every wifi card is a different story, thus knowing the exact model would slice the problem

Anyway, if the wifi card was ever detected, in the installed section of the app store, the store itself should be proposing you to install proprietary drivers